# Routing by means of OpenStreetMap with Qt and Maps.me?

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, qt, maps.me

I'm following the steps on this page:

1. https://github.com/mapsme/omim/blob/master/docs/MAPS.md
2. https://github.com/mapsme/omim/blob/master/docs/CONTRIBUTING.md

When I run this line `"omim/tools/unix/generate_mwm.sh source.pbf any_random_string_asdf`" I don't have an Error, then run Qt and Maps.me application appears but when I click on the route nothing happens.

What do I have to do? Should I execute something before?